# The meaning of @ character in php

Tags: php, syntax

I am a newbie in PHP.

I do not know the meaning of @, for example:

$key = @$_REQUEST['key'];

I have searched in google but can not find anything.

Some help me! Please !

Comment: It's designed to make debugging your code almost impossible and shooting yourself in the foot really easy.

Comment: bookmark/remember this page — http://php.net/@

Answer (score 4):

The `@` symbol tells the function to fail silently instead of dumping some sort of error message.  It is listed under [error control operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 2):

It suppresses any errors that the line would normally produce. In this case if the key doesn't exist, an error will occur but the error text will be silenced.

Answer (score 1):

It suppresses errors and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You've found the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)!

Answer (score 1):

[It suppresses warnings in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). In that example it could be used to suppress and undefined index warning, if `$_REQUEST['key']` doesn't exist. It's usually better practice to write:

```
$key = isset($_REQUEST['key']) ? $_REQUEST['key'] : 'default value for key here';
```